# Change font on text manipulation on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have a webpage with text input and monospaced font:

```
<input type="text" style="font-family: monospaced">
```

And this works like a charm on Android. But when I enter the "edit" mode on the device, when the keyboard pops up, the font changes back to the platfom specific one (not monospaced). When the editing is done and text field loses focus, it changes back to monospaced again.

The idea here is to change the text manipulation font to monospaced also when editing the text. Is there a way to do it from within HTML / CSS / Javascript? My first impression is "no", as this seems to be platform defined in the underlying TextView. But maybe my impression is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about an embedded WebView. Then it is possible.

You could add a [javascript interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) in Android. Then in your javascript you could add an event listener on the input fields, which will use the javascript interface to trigger an action on the native app. This action could also be changing the font-family of native components.

Comment: I am talking about web browsers on Android. Mainly the platform provided one.

Comment: Don't think that is possible then. Maybe with a custom url scheme to start an service on the device? But there other big problems arise.